Table cell/row color overflows line
Problem
I have a table that contains a subrow and columns for only the second column. I would now like to have a hline displayed for the sub-columns in the second column. I am able to do this, but whenever I then try to color the cells in the second row, the created line looses thickness.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\scalebox{0.7}{
\begin{tabular}{
  |p{\dimexpr.27\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% Adjusted column 1
  |p{\dimexpr.12\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% Adjusted column 2
  |p{\dimexpr.12\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% Adjusted column 3
  |p{\dimexpr.12\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% Adjusted column 4
  |p{\dimexpr.12\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% Adjusted column 5
  |p{\dimexpr.26\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}|% Adjusted column 6
  }
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3}
\textbf{Name external data} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3}\textbf{Drop-downs}} & \parbox[t]{\dimexpr1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}{\textbf{Name for data ingestion\\ into CRM}} \\
\arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\cellcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3} \rule{0pt}{3.5ex} \textbf{Model} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3} \textbf{Storage} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3} \textbf{Color} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3} \textbf{Grade} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3} \\
\hline
Apple iPhone 13 Mini 128GB-Black-Grade A+ & iPhone 13 mini & 128 & Midnight & Wie neu & iPhone 13 mini 128 GB Midnight – Wie neu\\
\hline
Samsung Galaxy S20 Plus 5G 128GB G986B DS-Black-Grade A & Samsung Galaxy S20 Plus & 128 & Cosmic Black & Wie neu & Samsung Galaxy S20 Plus 128 GB Cosmic Black – Wie neu\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Google Sheets Matching Example}
\label{tab:gsheet_matching_example}
\end{table}

\end{document}



\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\scalebox{0.7}{
\begin{tabular}{
  |p{\dimexpr.27\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% Adjusted column 1
  |p{\dimexpr.12\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% Adjusted column 2
  |p{\dimexpr.12\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% Adjusted column 3
  |p{\dimexpr.12\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% Adjusted column 4
  |p{\dimexpr.12\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% Adjusted column 5
  |p{\dimexpr.26\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}|% Adjusted column 6
  }
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3}
\textbf{Name external data} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3}\textbf{Drop-downs}} & \parbox[t]{\dimexpr1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}{\textbf{Name for data ingestion\\ into CRM}} \\
\arrayrulecolor{black}\cline{2-5}
 & \rule{0pt}{3.5ex} \textbf{Model} &  \textbf{Storage} &  \textbf{Color} &  \textbf{Grade} & \\
\hline
Apple iPhone 13 Mini 128GB-Black-Grade A+ & iPhone 13 mini & 128 & Midnight & Wie neu & iPhone 13 mini 128 GB Midnight – Wie neu\\
\hline
Samsung Galaxy S20 Plus 5G 128GB G986B DS-Black-Grade A & Samsung Galaxy S20 Plus & 128 & Cosmic Black & Wie neu & Samsung Galaxy S20 Plus 128 GB Cosmic Black – Wie neu\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Google Sheets Matching Example}
\label{tab:gsheet_matching_example}
\end{table}


QUESTION
How can I apply the coloring to the second row with keeping the line thickness from the second table?

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[l]ccccX[l]}[hvlines]
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,rowcolor= [HTML]{C5E0B3}]{\bfseries}
\Block{2-1}{Name external data} & \Block{1-4}{Drop-downs} &&&&
\Block{2-1}{Name for data ingestion into CRM} \\
& Model &  Storage &  Color &  Grade & \\
Apple iPhone 13 Mini 128GB-Black-Grade A+ & iPhone 13 mini & 128 & Midnight & Wie neu & iPhone 13 mini 128 GB Midnight – Wie neu\\
Samsung Galaxy S20 Plus 5G 128GB G986B DS-Black-Grade A & \Block[t]{}{Samsung Galaxy\\ S20 Plus} & 128 & Cosmic Black & Wie neu & Samsung Galaxy S20 Plus 128 GB Cosmic Black – Wie neu\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Google Sheets Matching Example}
\label{tab:gsheet_matching_example}
\end{table}

\end{document}


